# Create new column of data classified binomial without overwriting existing column of data

Tags: r

So I am trying to figure out how to take a column *Grad.Cat* from my data *College* and classify it as high or low values. But instead of changing the values to 'high' and 'low' in the same column in the dataframe, I want to create a new column of data called *highlow*.

How do I do what I'm doing with the following code, but instead create a new column of data that contains those values without overwriting the existing data.

```
College$Grad.Cat <- "low"
College$Grad.Cat[College$Grad.Rate>60] <- "high"
College$Grad.Cat <- factor(College$Grad.Cat, levels = c("low","high"))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `case_when`

```
library(tidyverse)
College <- College %>%
           mutate(Grad.Cat = factor(case_when(Grad.Rate > 60 ~ "high", 
                 TRUE ~ "low")))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
College$Grad.Cat <- factor(c("low", "high")[1 + (College$Grad.Rate > 60)])
```

Comment: Thank you! How does that create a new column of data though? Also what is %>%?

Comment: It is a pipe operator.  which connects the lhs output data and if needed can do further processing on that data